# Unable to display value in HTML text input box

Tags: html, input, textbox

I am unable to display a text present in the value of the input text box.

On inspecting the element, I found that the text box looks like

```
<input type="text" value="(424) 234-3243" placeholder="Phone Number" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd" name="phone" class="input-medium bfh-phone width9em" id="phone">
```

although, there is not text message displayed on the screen.

Any unrelated change in the html, brings the text back in the screen.

Please suggest what can I do in this regard?

Comment: Are you sure? Clear cache and everything and try again! Code looks fine to me, may be you're missing something minor

Comment: It does work in jsFiddle (on Chrome 31).

Comment: Dhaval, Yes I am sure because all my fields are correct except all the phone number and fax fields which have similar htmls.

Comment: I think you may have issue in your css classes which you have applied on your **textbox** `input-medium bfh-phone width9em`

Comment: Could it be that the text is actually there but it's somehow invisible? Give a look at the CSS especially to: `input`,`.input-medium` and `.bfh-phone` selectors.

Comment: Yes thats right bfh-phone is causing the issue coz that is used for the data-format. But unfortunately there seems to be nothing becuming invisible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hey thanks to all for your responses, although I found the solution to be

```
<input type="text" data-number="(424) 234-3243" placeholder="Phone Number" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd" name="phone" class="input-medium bfh-phone width9em" id="phone">
```

i.e. replacing the "value=" by "data-number="...:)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/Ly3pJ/

```
<input type="text" value="(424) 234-3243" placeholder="Phone Number" data-format="(ddd) ddd-dddd" name="phone" class="input-medium bfh-phone width9em" id="phone">
```

That seems to be correct, as you could see on jsfiddle. This proves that what you did is correct. Maybe you did something in the css or jquery so that the input is empty?

Comment: Acelasi Eu yeah its strange because like I mentioned in my comment all the phone and fax fields are behaving this way and a single irrelevant change in the html from firebug fixes the issue.

Comment: what browser are you using?

Comment: do you have this issue on chrome for example?